# Crystal report paremeters to be printed more than 1 times in detail Section

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have `crystal report` with parameters only in C#
i place parameter in detail section.
I want these paremeters to be printed more than 1 times(which will be given at run time ).
how can i achieve this?

Comment: what data is your report displaying? the details section of the report will be printed once for every record in the report data.

Comment: I am printing only Parameters.Report has `NO tables`.

Comment: is the number of times you want to print fixed? or variable?

Comment: Number of times Print will be Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just print it via a loop in a formula?

```
local numbervar TimesToPrint := 8;
local numbervar i; //for-loop counter 
local stringvar out; //return variable

for i := 1 to TimesToPrint do
    out := out + {?YourParameter} + chr(13); //format your output

out
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable number of times you need the parameters to print is "reasonable" you could create that number of report footer sections and place the parameters in every one of these. Then set the section suppression formula to suppress based on the number of times you want it to print.

If the number of times you want them printed can be quite high you will probably want to use some sort of data source. You can then place the parameters in the detail section and use the parameter to drive the number of records returned.

Comment: I agree with your concept.But can you give some sample report - it will be help full